# Stored Procedure Update statement not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

Back again with another stored procedure problem, I want to make a 1 click submit then update with ASP.Net, but seems not working for me..

Here's the code in my class

```
public void assignofclass(string course, string id)
{
        myCon.Open();
        SqlCommand saveCmd = new SqlCommand("assignclass", myCon);
        saveCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        saveCmd.Parameters.Add("@userid", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = id;
        saveCmd.Parameters.Add("@course", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = course;
        saveCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myCon.Close();
}
```

Code-behind:

```
using ClassLibrary1;
Class1 cs = new Class1();
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cs.assignofclass(TextBox1.Text, DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
        Response.Write("<script> alert('" + TextBox1.Text + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "')</script>");
         //just to make sure the textbox1 and dropdownlist1 is not giving a null value
    }
```

and lastly, the stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.assignclass
@userid nchar(10),
@course nchar(10)
AS
Update users Set 
course = @course
Where userid = @userid
RETURN
```

What seems to be the problem here? I can't seem to update my table, btw this is the table

Table name: **users**

```
userid  nchar(10)
firstname   nchar(20)
middlename  nchar(20)
lastname    nchar(20)
course  nchar(10)
usertype    nchar(10)
apassword   nchar(20)
grade   decimal(18, 2)
```

`myCon` declaration:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
public class Class1
{
    public static string ConStr = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=........
    SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(ConStr);
```

somewhere up there, my class would be somewhere after this code

Comment: Is `id` a string value?

Comment: What does "*Not Working*" mean?

Comment: Hmmm, `nChar(..)` is an unusual datatype choice.  Why wouldn't you use `NVarChar(..)` instead?

Comment: Have you tried setting the SqlParameter to the same parameter type used by the table and stored procedure instead of NVarChar?

Comment: @RBarryYoung not working, i meant is even if it runs, the table is not updating the way i want it to work. and yeah sorry about the nChar part, i will change it as soon as i made this Update statement to work

Comment: @YuriyGalanter if your refering to the class, yes that is a string.

Comment: What do you mean "not updating the way I want"? - It doesn't update at all? Updates wrong items?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter i mean no it's not really updating at all. seems like an SQL error but cant seem to find the error, i've been changing the value but still no result

Comment: Can you try in you SQL condition `Where LTRIM(RTRIM(userid)) = @userid` ?

Comment: where is `myCon` declared?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter still not working

Comment: @AthanSubion ok, what about `Where LTRIM(RTRIM(userid)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(@userid))` ?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter still not working sir,

Comment: Is the ID alphanumeric? Can it come in different cases upper/lower?

Comment: Are you creating the connection object correctly, show all your code for this - possibly in the ctor?

Comment: as of now, userinfo have only 2 values, 1st is "admin" all small letters and 2nd is "0", just plain 0.

@christiandev yes the connection is correct, in fact i have created an insert statement with stored procedure and its working. but when i came here with update, i dont know why its now updating.

Comment: Actually, the `NChar` may be causign the problem, because the passed `NVarChar(*)->NChar(10) @userid` may not be matching the `NChar userid` of the table in the `WHERE` clause (because `[N]CHAR` types have to be space-filled before matching is tested and the spaces are significant).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding different types of parameters in your code than the one in the stored procedure.

At last I got it, here's the problem:

```
cs.assignofclass(TextBox1.Text, DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
```

and

```
public void assignofclass(string id, string course)
```

at first, the code was

```
public void assignofclass(string course, string id)
```

wherein `Textbox1.Text = userid` and `DropDownList1.SelectedValue = course`

Silly me, from now on I am going to RENAME all objects into their specific use. That's the lesson I learned today. thank you all for helping me.

Comment: make sure you passing userid which is present in your database.